# format of image is wrong when using multer to upload

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using multer to do the image upload for my project, the way I used it is, in app.js:

```
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(multer({
    dest: './public/images'
}).single('file1'));
```

looks like the upload is successful cause I can see something been added under *images* folder but when I open the folder, there's just a file like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your image. Multer just renamed it.

Comment: how can I use it? I tried to include the image in my post with the following markdown syntax but failed to load: ![](/images/imageName.jpg)

Comment: I think in your upload form, you can find that name in the `filename` property of the file. And the `destination` property should give you the path to the file. So you can use those to get the path to use in your code.
For more information you can check the multer on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Comment: ur right, it is indeed the image there but just got renamed by multer, better to custom the rename process at setup.